# Kinect Studio crashes XNA application‎s

Tags: xna, kinect

When I try to connect Kinect Studio to an XNA application the app crashes.
I tested it with the Samples from the Developer Toolkit.

I use VS2010 and W7 64bit and a Kinect for Xbox.

The WPF examples are running fine.
The Error I get when running the XNABasics example is following (Sorry its partly in German):

Problemsignatur:

Problemereignisname:    APPCRASH

Anwendungsname:    XnaBasics.exe

Anwendungsversion:    1.0.0.0

Anwendungszeitstempel:    504a7d42

Fehlermodulname:    KinectStudioConnector32.dll

Fehlermodulversion:    1.5.2.222

Fehlermodulzeitstempel:    5015e310

Ausnahmecode:    c0000005

Ausnahmeoffset:    00007198

Betriebsystemversion:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Gebietsschema-ID:    1031

Zusatzinformation 1:    867d

Zusatzinformation 2:    867dcfba8c79c419cc83e8596b854db9

Zusatzinformation 3:    614f

Zusatzinformation 4:    614fd16b3adacbd899bb6a7de15896be

When I last run it about a week ago everything was working fine.
Could it be because of a graphic card driver update or something similar?

Comment: Try reinstalling the Kinect SDk

Comment: I reinstalled  Kinect SDK, the Toolkit and the XNA Studio but no change.
But I noticed that it only crashes when I run it from inside Visual Studio.
Starting the .exe (Debug or Release) from the folder and connecting works alright.

Comment: I just took the Kinect Studio 1.5.1.0 from the 1.5.1 SDK.
The rest of 1.5.2 seems Works fine.

Hope the Kinect for Windows update next Month will fix this :-)